# jQuery-Datatables dropdowns ONLY for some columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Using this code, and all examples i've seen, i can add dropdowns to ALL columns like in the picture:

[image]

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'lfBrtip',

        initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.header()))
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
.......
    }
```

**How can i add dropdowns ONLY for column 2 and 3 for example?**

Answer (score 2):

You should use `each` for getting index of columns to set drop down list.

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'lfBrtip',

        initComplete: function () {
        var api = this.api();
         this.api().columns().eq(0).each( function ( index ) {
           if(index == 1 || index == 2)
           {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(api.column(index).header()))
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
              var i = 0;
              api.column(index).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
              } );
           }
        } );
.......
    }
```

Comment: The editor is not complaining, but in console i get  `column.header is not a function`. I can't tell why.

Comment: i have change the header

Comment: It sort of worked, but now i have weird data in the dropdowns; see [photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4nUvzf87W8KcU5JS2NZWkxVUFE/view)

Comment: your image needs permission

Comment: oops, sorry! fixed now.

Comment: how about now??Edited as :`api.column(index).data().unique().sort().each(`

Comment: Actually now selecting an option gives 0 results in the table! I did not test this when i accepted the answer before.

Comment: that is another problem, the reason why you get zero is because you did not get the data from from `row(index).data()` when you select. My answer has fulfilled your question already.

Comment: Does it work?? after you get the data from `row(index).data()`

Comment: I tried poking row(index).data() here and there in the function, but the truth is i don't understand what u mean.

Comment: not "here" or "there", you should making a new function of `$("select").on("change",function(){table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data()});` and not include in `initComplete`, also make the function after `DataTable` function.

Comment: This is a [Demo](http://live.datatables.net/jevagolo/3/edit) with most of my code. If u want please take a look.

Comment: The search has been performed correctly, the main problem is why you adding `^` and `$` in the string.

Comment: it cannot be search because you added `^` and `$` in string. have you try that the `.search( val ? val : '', true, false )`? you may try as i think.

Comment: That seems to work, but it's adding the selected dropdown value to the Search field. The dropdown can't be linked to the search input.

Comment: i give you some hints on your code, thats researching will reach your purpose:
https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is add the following two lines

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    dom: 'lfBrtip',

    initComplete: function () {
    this.api().columns().every( function () {
        if(this[0] == 2 || this[0] == 3){//add
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
            .appendTo( $(column.header()))
            .on( 'change', function () {
                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                    $(this).val()
                );

                column
                    .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                    .draw();
            } );

        column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
        } );
    } // add
    } );
    // ...
}
```